# Newtonsoft json serializer returns empty object

Tags: json, json.net

Ok - I've been beating my head against this for a few of hours now. Time to ask for help.

I have just upgraded my Web application project to ASP.NET MVC 4 RC, and the new WebApi.
My web api method is now returning EMPTY json "{}" - even though my object is fully populated.

I have replace the serializer with my own MediaTypeFormatter that also calls the Newtonsoft Json serializer, just so I can hook in and see things working.
What I see is an object going in to the serializer, and coming out as "{}".

This USED to work before I upgraded.

This is my object

```
[Serializable]
public class Parameters
{
    public string ApplicantName { get; set; }
}
```

And I am just calling:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Parameters(){ Name = "test" });
```

I get back

```
"{}"
```

Whats going on??

[EDIT]

Someone else having the same problem... after running through the Newtonsoft source code, I can see we're having the exact same problem from a recent change.

http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/357850

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - there have been numerous changes, which result is some pretty radical changes to the Json output. These changes also include how custom TypeConverters are applied.

I have written a basic resolver which (for us at least) causes the Newtonsoft serializer to behave more like a basic Serializable object serializer - i.e. serializes all PROPERTIES, and doesnt use custom TypeConverters...

```
/// <summary>
/// A resolver that will serialize all properties, and ignore custom TypeConverter attributes.
/// </summary>
public class SerializableContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach (var p in properties)
            p.Ignored = false;

        return properties;
    }

    protected override Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (contract is Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonStringContract)
            return CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        return contract;
    }
}
```

*** REGISTRATION ***
In your MvcApplication "Application_Start"...

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
    .JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
        new SerializableContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true
        };
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me workaround my issue of JSON.NET serializer not serializing public string properties that happen to have an empty string value.....I need them included in the resulting JSON as the javascript is expecting the properties to exist

Comment: What should I do with that ?