# Ignoring TypeConverter attribute in Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, json.net, nest

I have reference to several classes defined in an external library that contain a TypeConverter attribute. Due to this attribute, Json.Net, and consequently Nest, is incorrectly serializing these objects. The correct way to serialize these objects is to ignore the TypeConverter attribute and make use of the object properties. In searching Stack Overflow I have found a method that successfully does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044639/newtonsoft-json-serializer-returns-empty-object).

Unfortunately, when I apply this method to Nest in the following way, the resultant objects do not contain the necessary _type, _index and _id fields.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(_Uri);
// Tell Json.Net to ignore custom TypeConverters
settings.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(m => m.ContractResolver = new SerializableContractResolver());
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Since the resultant JSON does not contain the critical fields, all index requests fail. Is there a way to have Nest ignore the TypeConverter attributes while still ensuring the objects contain the necessary additional fields for Elasticsearch requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing a contractresolver that ignores TypeConverters you are applying a bazooka to kill a fly in my opinion.

We also rely heavily on typeconverters to write **our** objects correctly.

If the classes in your external library do not quite represent the way they should look in your elasticsearch index I'd recommend create a specific `POCO` for NEST that does. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is a great way to convert instances of your external library to instances of indexable object.

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Laarman's suggestion is probably the correct solution. However, I decided to unblock myself with the following hack:

I continue to use the method defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044639/newtonsoft-json-serializer-returns-empty-object). I then correctly serialize the external object into JSON. I deserialize the object into a dynamic type. Finally I pass this object to Nest.

```
// Strip away TypeConverter attributes -- super hacky
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
descriptor.Index<Object>(op => op.Index(index).Type(type).Id(id).Document(payload));
```