# Newtonsoft.JSON serialization results in a sole string with the object's type

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an object of class `ProcessStartInfo`

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "path",
    Arguments = "args",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "runas"
};
```

And for logging purpose I want serialize it to JSON.
My code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(psi);
```

`json` contains:

> "System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"

How to serialize properties intead type name?

Comment: It's because of the `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]` attribute on `ProcessStartInfo`. See for example [Newtonsoft json serializer returns empty object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044639/newtonsoft-json-serializer-returns-empty-object).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. I need it in one place. Own ContractResolver is too much work ;-) Is there no switch in JSON.NET for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CodeCaster specified in the comment, the issue is with `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]`, you need to create new `JsonObjectContract` for that '`ExpandableObjectConverter`' attribute assigned to type.

New contract resolver can be created for the type having 'ExpandableObjectConverter' attibute :

```
public class SerializableExpandableContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(objectType).Contains(new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))))
        {
            return CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        }
        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use above contract resolver while serializing in following way:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(psi,
                new JsonSerializerSettings() {ContractResolver = new SerializableExpandableContractResolver()});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Based on @CodeCaster comment I wrote something similar :-)