# WebApi returns empty JSON instead of serialized object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

So simple yet I know not why it fails.  In a WebAPI 2.0 ASP.NET MVC (pre-core) controller method, I have this:

```
[Route("GetItem")]
[HttpGet]
public ItemVM GetItem() {
    var item = new ItemVM();  // Constructor initializes
    return item;
}
```

When I run the code, the debugger shows this in item:

```
item          {ViewModels.ItemVMs.ItemVM}
    firstItem {ViewModels.ItemVMs.FirstItemVM}
        id       0
        archived false
        name     null
```

Yet WebAPI returns only this:

```
{}
```

I have tried suggestions like  [Newtonsoft json serializer returns empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044639/newtonsoft-json-serializer-returns-empty-object) but Visual Studio 2017 says `CreateProperties` does not exist to override.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

LOL I told you it is a simple answer.  Here's the class:

```
public class ItemVM {
    FirstItemVM firstItem { get; set; }
    
    public ItemVM() {
        this.firstItem = FirstItemVM.ToMap( new Entities.Item());
    }
}

public class FirstItemVM {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool archived { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public static readonly Expression<Func<Entities.FirstItem, FirstItemVM>> 
        Map (e) => new FirstItemVM {
            id = e.id,
            archived = e.archived,
            name = e.name
    };
    public static readonly Func<Entities.FirstItem, FirstItemVM>
        ToMap = FirstItemVM.Map.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Is that firstItem public?

Comment: Please attach `class ItemVM` code too.

Comment: @evk You are correct.  Please post that as an answer.  LOL  Very simple mistake, but worth noting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `ItemVM.firstItem` is not public (for example, internal), and JSON serializer will only serialize public properties by default (unless you non-public property explicitly to be serialized).